# Why does replaceObjectAtIndex depend on whether or not I use a new definition in the loop?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have two codes. Not working is the following:

```
NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<[dataSetArray count]; i++) {
    tmpArray = (NSMutableArray *) [dataSetArray objectAtIndex:i];
    // OR use: tmpArray = dataSetArray[i]
         ... doing stuff
    [tmpArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:tmpStr];
}
```

While this works:

```
for (int i=0; i<[dataSetArray count]; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[dataSetArray objectAtIndex:i]];
         ... doing stuff
    [tmpArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:tmpStr];
}
```

Two questions:

1. The first code doesn't yield an `NSMutableArray`. Why? I declare it
   above.
2. Is there a better way to obtain the same result. I just
   dislike defining variables in a loop. This makes the code
   unreadable.

--- edit:

Here the full code:

Datatypes are:

dataSetArray: NSMutableArray. However, its contents (i.e. dataSetArray[i]) are NSArrays (I read them into the program from an excel file).

```
NSString       *tmpStr   = [[NSString alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<[dataSetArray count]; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[dataSetArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    for (int j=0; j<[tmpArray count]; j++) {
        if ( [dataSetArray[0][j] isEqualToString:@"Number"] ) {continue;}
        tmpStr = (NSString *) [tmpArray objectAtIndex:j];

        // replace single backslash by double-backslash:
        tmpStr = [tmpStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\\\\"];

        // replace first dollar sign by "<p>\\[" and second by "\\]</p>"
        // Use a methode defined in the NSString+Extension
        tmpStr = [tmpStr replaceTexFormulaSigns:tmpStr];

        //NSLog(@"j=%d", j);
        //NSLog(@"tmpArray is of type: %@", [tmpArray class]);
        //NSLog(@" tmpStr is of type: %@", [tmpStr class]);
        [tmpArray replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:tmpStr];
    }
    [dataSetArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:tmpArray];
}
```

So even if I use your suggestion, I am still facing the same problem with the inner array.

Comment: What does `dataSetArray` actually contain? Is it an array of `NSArray` or an array of `NSMutableArray`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first code doesn't yield a NSMutableArray. Why? I declare it above.

The declaration of the reference variable `tmpArray` does not change the type of the *referred object*. It is still an (immutable) array.

The creation of the mutable array at the very beginning of the first snippet is without any meaning, because the reference to it is overridden.

> Is there a better way to obtain the same result. I just dislike defining variables in a loop. This makes the code unreadable.

Yes. The second example works in a way, but do something completely different. (It always creates a new array with a single item in it. No, that's not true. It shouldn't compile at all.)

You should do:

```
NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [dataSetArray mutableCopy];
for (int i=0; i<[dataSetArray count]; i++) 
{
  …
  [tmpArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:tmpStr];
}
```

You should *really* get some additional knowledge about objects and object references.

Comment: So what I really have is an array of an array. dataSetArray is a NSMutable Array, while its contents are NSArrays. So even if I use your suggestion, I still have the same problem with the inner array.

Comment: You have to create a new outer (mutable) array by mutable copying the inner arrays into the new array. From where do you get the array? Can you create it mutable from the very beginning?

Comment: I import the data from an excel-file. In principle I could use a mutable array from the beginning, however, this is not why I ask the question. As I wrote from above: The code is working, thou not nice. Hence, I'd like to learn how to convert between data types.

Comment: With nested collections copying to mutable variants is always a deep copy. And you have to do it yourself. This is why some APIs for creating such structures (Plist-Deserialization, JSON deserialization) allows to create mutable variants.